# How to cast expression in select clause with high performance

Tags: casting, hana, hana-sql-script

I have a table and want to convert a column of type decimal to an integer based on a condition. I need to do this as performant as possible.

My currently working query looks like this:

    `select *, (case when C_CUSTKEY < 20 then 1 else 0 end) as bit
    from TPCH.CUSTOMER`

However I'm trying to improve this. Is it possible to do the conversion on the fly, e.g. something like this:

    `select *, cast((C_CUSTKEY < 20) as integer) as bit
    from TPCH.CUSTOMER`

Or even for a simpler version like:

    `select *, (C_CUSTKEY < 20) as bit
    from TPCH.CUSTOMER`

No matter what functionality I use, I always get the following error:

`sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "<"`

**Update 1**

So for better understanding an actual usecase of what I want to do is as following:

`select ( (case when col1 < x then 1 else 0 end)
        + (case when col2 > y then 2 else 0 end) ) as bitset
from TPCH.CUSTOMER`

In general there can be a large number of 'case when' expressions (>100).

- Now the first problem is that the expression is very slow and I need to improve performance so I wanted to know if its possible to to the conversion on the fly smth like `2 * to_int(col2 > y)` but I cannot find a way to do this.
- Second problem is when I have many 'case when' expressions then I get the following error: `SQL internal parse tree depth exceeds its maximum: parse tree depth exceeds its maximum:255`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about the use case here. 
Generally speaking, you cannot have a different data type for the same column at the same time. That's a fundamental constraint of the relational data model.

If however, the requirement merely is to have an indicator for "value in C_CUSTKEY < 20" then using the CASE statement is a straightforward way to do this.
In order to avoid this evaluation at query time, you could create a calculated column for this.

```
alter table TPCH.CUSTOMER add ("BIT" integer 
                                generated always as 
                                case 
                                  when ("C_CUSTKEY" < 20) 
                                  then 1 
                                  else 0 
                                end);
```

Concerning the syntax errors: well, you're just not using the correct syntax. Check the example above for a correctly working example.

Comment: that's what I'm currently doing but I actually don't want to materialize the BIT column. I'm also aware that this is not the correct syntax because (field < value) is not supported in select clause, that's why I asked if there is a way to do this.

Comment: @Jan the example I posted does work on SPS11 just as posted. If you don't want to materialise it, simply use the case condition in the projection part of your select command.

Comment: so you mean as I wrote it in the question? That's too slow for my purpose. I need to improve the performance of the 'case when' expression, e.g. if i have ```(case when ("C_CUSTKEY" < 20) then 1 else 0 end) +  (case when ("C_CUSTKEY" > 40) then 2 else 0 end) + ...``` with many more 'case when' expressions it'll be very slow.

Comment: You might be better off describing your full requirement here instead of coming back with additional conditions and constraints after I spent time and effort on your question.

Comment: The question contains my full requirement. It's just the basic usecase of what I need. The core question is still the same but I will extend the question later today.